# Messages getting dropped, never reached task executor thread

Tags: spring-integration

I noticed a very strange issue today, message was received but it never got processed. In below configuration i have 5 listeners configured to read from a JMS queue, my wiretap logger prints that a JMS message was received but then there is no trace of it getting processed by the task executor thread, rest of the processing runs fine. It just happened for few messages at some point of time. I have the all relevant configuration provided below; any help to correct it would be appreciated.

```
 <jms:message-driven-channel-adapter                             
                            id="IN1"                                
                            destination="replyQueue"  
                            channel="InChannel" 
                            auto-startup="false" 
                            max-messages-per-task="20"
                            receive-timeout="10000"
                            max-concurrent-consumers="1" 
                            concurrent-consumers="1"                                                            
                            idle-consumer-limit="1"
                            idle-task-execution-limit="1"                               
                            recovery-interval="60000"/>
<jms:message-driven-channel-adapter                                  
                            id="IN2"                                
                            destination="replyQueue"  
                            channel="InChannel" 
                            auto-startup="false" 
                            max-messages-per-task="20"
                            receive-timeout="10000"
                            max-concurrent-consumers="1" 
                            concurrent-consumers="1"                                                            
                            idle-consumer-limit="1"
                            idle-task-execution-limit="1"                               
                            recovery-interval="60000"/>




<int:channel id="InChannel">
<int:dispatcher task-executor="saveTaskExecutor"/>
    <int:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap channel="MyLogger"/>
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>
```

The Wiretap logger prints the message that was received.

```
<int:logging-channel-adapter logger-name="MsgInLogger" id="MyLogger" level="INFO" expression="'received payload for processing'+ payload " />
```

The task executor is defined as below, my understating is, this has unbounded queue so there is no issue related to number of messages, also this happened when the volume was minimal.

```
<beans:bean id="saveTaskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
<beans:property name="corePoolSize" value="20" />
<beans:property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
</beans:bean>
```

The saveTaskExecutor thread is going to take very long to process a message before it can take next, not sure if there is any timeout or expiry sort of things happening out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There shouldn't be any way for them to be lost, but why are you doing it this way instead of simply setting `concurrent-consumers` to 20 and let the container take care of your flow rate?

The way you have it; if your server crashes you'll lose all the messages in the executor's queue. You should also set `acknowledge-mode="transacted"` or use a `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` to avoid losing in-process messages during a server crash.

Comment: Right, but this is a workaround from our previous issue where IBM MQ apis are not thread safe and resulted in deadlock, so i need to separately run consumers. The messages indeed got lost, not sure why. There is no trace of them in log once they are received, checked threads they all are running fine and also the newer messages are going fine.